# How can I animate a UIBezierPath drawing to appear slowly as opposed to right away?

Tags: animation, ios6, core-animation

I'm writing an app (XCode 4.6) that displays drawings of various different paths - for now it's just straight lines and bezier paths, but eventually it will get more complicated. I am currently not using any layers and the display is actually pretty simple.

my drawRect code looks like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect :(int) points :(drawingTypes) type //:(Boolean) initial
{
    //CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect appframe= [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];


    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    _helper = [[Draw2DHelper alloc ] initWithBounds :appframe.size.width  :appframe.size.height :type];

    CGPoint startPoint = [_helper generatePoint] ;

    [_uipath moveToPoint:startPoint];
    [_uipath setLineWidth: 1.5];

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor);

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.center.y, self.center.x) ;

    [_helper createDrawing :type :_uipath :( (points>0) ? points : defaultPointCount) :center];


    [_uipath stroke];
}


- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (_uipath == NULL)
       _uipath = [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
    else
        [_uipath removeAllPoints];

    [self drawRect:rect  :self.graphPoints :self.drawingType ];
}
```

The actual path is generated by a helper object (_helper). I would like to animate the display of this path to appear slowly over a few seconds as it is being drawn - what is the easiest and fastest way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean "appear slowly?" I assume you do not mean fade in all over at once, but rather mean that you want it to look like the path is being drawn with a pen?

To do that, do the following:

Create a CAShapeLayer the same size as your view and add it as a sublayer of your view.
Get the CGPath from your bezier path.

Install the CGPath into your shapeLayer.

Create a CABasicAnimation that animates the value of the shape layer's strokeEnd property from 0.0 to 1.0. That will cause the shape to be drawn as if it was being traced from beginning to end. You probably want a path that contains a single, contiguous sub-path. If you want it to circle back and connect, make it a closed path.

There are all kinds of cool tricks you can do with shape layers and animating changes to the path. and it's settings (like strokeStart and strokeEnd, stokeColor, fillColor, etc.) If you animate the path itself, you have to make sure the beginning path and ending path have the same number of control points internally. (And path arcs are tricky because the path has a different number of control points depending on the angle of the arc.)

Comment: thank you so much - is there a code sample you can point me to? Does the CAShapeLayer need to be declared in drawREct or earlier in the code?